# How to add return map values into wrapper class

Tags: apex

I am working on one apex class which is returning MAP.

Can anyone help me out how to write wrapper which will add the returned map into wrapper class.

I want to pass returned map values to LWC component to display it

```
public class LTNG_HTERCA_RightTagWrapper {
@AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
public static Map<string,List<Shadow_Note__c>> populateTaggedNotesForCase(Id RecordId){
    String caseRecordId = '';
    List<Root_Cause_Analysis__c> rcaRecords = [Select Id, Case__c from Root_Cause_Analysis__c where Id =: RecordId order by CreatedDate desc];
    if(rcaRecords.size() > 0)
        caseRecordId = rcaRecords[0].Case__c;
    Map<string,List<Shadow_Note__c>> res = new Map<string,List<Shadow_Note__c>>();
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Shadow_Note__c.Note_Tag__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple =fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    for (Schema.PicklistEntry a:ple ){
            res.put(a.value , new List<Shadow_Note__c>());
    }
    List<LTNG_HTERCA_RightTagWrapper> shadowNotesTagList = new List<LTNG_HTERCA_RightTagWrapper>();
    List<Shadow_Note__c> allshadownotes = [SELECT Note__c,Note_Tag__c,Date_Time_Created_in_CSOne__c,CreatedBy_Name__c From Shadow_Note__c 
    WHERE Case__c =: caseRecordId AND Note_Tag__c != null 
    ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC];
    for(Shadow_Note__c sn: allshadownotes){
        List<String> noteTags = sn.Note_Tag__c.split(';');
        for(String tag: noteTags){
            if(res.containsKey(tag)){
                List<Shadow_Note__c> notesList = res.get(tag);
                notesList.add(sn);
                res.put(tag, notesList);
                system.debug('res is ++: ' + res);
            }
        }
    }
    System.debug('the result is:' + JSON.serializePretty(res));
    return res;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to dynamically cast to `Wrapper` from some `Map` you can do it like this.

```
Map<String, Object> obj;// some values

WrapperClass wrapper = (WrapperClass) JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(obj), WrapperClass.class);
```

Comment: hello, thanks a lot for helping me out in this issue, actually I want to pass those map values to LWC component to display it

Comment: then you can just return the map (or Object), what is the issue with that?